# Deciding number of threads in SOA Application (using Servlet)

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, cpu

I have an SOA application which consists of many servlets. When client submits the requests, my application connects to 4 external applications, exchanges data between them and provides the result.

Now, due to these 4 connections, the response of requests gets delayed considerably. Hence, we are planning to separate these 4 calls into threads so that the main thread can respond back quickly saying 'we are processing your data'.

The question is, how many threads should I start for these tasks? I can do all of the tasks in a single thread vs 4 different threads. What is the optimal solution?

Also, what affects CPU most? Number of threads OR length of the duration of execution of a particular thread?
My application receives 5 to 7 requests per second. So, what would be better? 1 separate (and longer running) thread OR 4 separate (but shorter running) threads per request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads you should start depends on the number of independent tasks you have. The more task/module/function(whatever you call) you have , the more threads you can start for each task/module.  Based on the independent work to be done  concurrently ,  you need to know how many threads you should use and how to utilize them effectively

> what affects CPU most? Number of threads OR length of the duration of execution of a particular thread? 
>   .

That seems to be a trivial question.Both will effect. Maybe not. Depends on the application/code you have.But that should not be a problem.